# Add 30 days to date (mm/dd/yyyy) then return string (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have the function below which takes a string from the datepicker and turns it into a date object so I can add 30 days to it. From there I am trying to return the new date as a string with 30 days added to it, in the format of (mm/dd/yy).

When the first alert fires it correctly adds 30 days to the selected date and shows this for selcted date as "05/03/2011":

> Thu Jun 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

The second alert shows

> 5/2/2011

Seems I can't correctly format the date and take "05/03/2011" and return "06/02/2011". I could just do month + 1, but could do with some help please and show me what I am doing wrong.

```
  $('#sign_date').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 

          var d = new Date(dateText);
          d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30);

          alert(d);

          var date = d.getDate();
          var month = d.getMonth();
          var year = d.getFullYear();

          alert(month+'/'+date +'/'+year)

      }
  });
```

Also I think they way I am doing it will show days and month as e.g. Jan = 1 and 1st = 1 and I would like it to be Jan = 01 and 1st = 01

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For leading zeros:

```
// add leading zero if the length equals 1
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10)   day   = "0" + day;
```

Be sure to add 1 to your month prior to using this code, too, since `getMonth()` returns a 0 for January, and so on:

```
 var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
```

Comment: I can add 30 days but cant seem to return the date in the correct format

Comment: @jim, sorry, I was finishing up my answer while I submitted what I thought was the first half of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Surprise, surprise... The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the range 0..11.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Kelly works to me

Just changed this

```
if(month<9) month = "0"+(month+1);
if(date<10) day = "0"+date;
```

Comment: With your current code, if the original `month` == 9, you'll end up with `010`.

Comment: Mmmm you are right. It should be (month<9) cause I need months from 1-12 and not from 0-11